# Java Swing - Can't use AWT Graphics to draw a circle

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

Before I start, please note that I am only able to edit the sections of code below. I am unable to edit any code within the provided jar file.

I have a TurtleGraphics project where I issue commands and then the turtle follows that command.

The project has a dependancy, a jar file, which is available at https://github.com/dnorfolk8/StackOverflowHelp.

As requested within the comments, the documentation for the class within the jar file is available at http://mullier.uk/LBU/OOP2020/JarDocumentation/index.html.

In my project I have 2 classes, a class called Main and a class called ExtendedTurtleGraphics - This uses inheritance to extend the class within the jar file. Within the ExtendedTurtleGraphics class I have used the code below to override a method within the TurtleGraphics class.

```
import uk.ac.leedsbeckett.oop.TurtleGraphics;
import java.awt.*;

public class ExtendedTurtleGraphics extends TurtleGraphics {

    @Override
    public void circle(int radius) {
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, (radius * 10), (radius * 10));
    }
}
```

Within the Main class (code below), I call a method called drawLine and the method called circle. The drawLine method does as it says, it draws a line, with a specified colour and from one point to another. However, the circle doesn't draw onto the screen.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtendedTurtleGraphics gp = new ExtendedTurtleGraphics();
        JFrame MainFrame = new JFrame();
        MainFrame.add(gp);
        MainFrame.setSize(815, 480);
        MainFrame.setResizable(false);
        MainFrame.setVisible(true);
        gp.drawLine(Color.red, 10, 10, 60, 60);
        gp.circle(10);
    }
}
```

I am unsure on how to get the circle to draw on the graphics panel. Any help solving this issue would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any answers given.

Comment: The `TurtleGraphics` class extends from a `JPanel` so `Graphics g = this.getGraphics();` is an entirely wrong way to go about custom painting. Instead override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method & do all painting there.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hi, thank you for the answer, after trying for the last 6 hours I have had no luck with solving my issue. I am constantly getting back to the beginning, the issue within the original post. Would it be possible for you to provide some example code that could be useful in solving the issue?

Comment: Sure. Look through [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A418556+paintcomponent). Many of them include code. Unless the code is based on the code in the question, it will use (mostly) best design practices throughout.

Comment: @Andrew After looking at the answers that you had linked, I managed to get the circle to paint on to the canvas, However, I am stuck again as I am unsure on how to only get it to paint when the statement is present within the paint(Graphics g) method. I'm not sure on how to get it draw when the 'circle' method is called. Are you able to help with this?

Comment: *"within the paint(Graphics g) method."* You apparently were not looking at those questions carefully. They would be using the **`paintComponent(..)`** method. *"I'm not sure on how to get it draw when the 'circle' method is called."* If it's a one off circle, have a `boolean paintCircle = false;` attribute, set it to true on button click, and check it in **`paintComponent(..)`** method. Then call `repaint()`.

Comment: @Andrew I managed to get a one off circle but unfortunately, that isn't what I want. I would like another circle to be drawn every time the command is called.

Comment: *"I would like another circle to be drawn every time the command is called. .."* Then add them to a list structure (like an `ArrayList`) and in the paint component method iterate the list and draw each one. Data structures like vector and array list are things you should already be familiar with - they are Java / programming 101.